# Installing eclipse Web Tools Platform (WTP) - update site does not work?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-wtp, eclipse-3.4

I'm trying to install the WTP (web platform tools) to my Eclipse installation so I can get the XSL transformations working. The base Eclipse they installed for me here was the plain Java IDE (the splash screen says "Ganymede" if that means anything). Looking at [this site](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/xsl-tools), the URL to get the download should be here: http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/updates/ ...But when I give that URL to the Eclipse update manager, I get an error telling me: "No repository found at http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/updates/"

Anyone else had this problem? Anyone know what might be up? Anyone know how to get the xsl-transform plugin installed?

**EDIT:**

I should have mentioned before that I want to find a way to do this without installing any new instances of Eclipse. This process will eventually be sent to several other developers who already have Eclipse (same version that I'm testing with) and I'd rather just do an in-place upgrade rather than have everyone go and install a new product.

**UPDATE:**

I found another plugin, [Xcarecrows 4 XML](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/xcarecrows-4-xml) which can also do XSL transforms. The interface is ugly and seems more than a little quirky, but it's also a small download, and at least it runs and transforms. Unless I can find an easy way to get WTP working, I'll probably just stick with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I can probably get it working if I do a clean install of Eclipse. I can do that on my machine, but not the other team members' machines (at least not without going through many emails and paper work) so I'm going to say that [XCarecrows 4 XML](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/xcarecrows-4-xml) is the solution. It is able to do XSL transformations in Eclipse 3.4 and doesn't require anything else to be installed. Since XSLT is all I need, the plugin will do.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it figured out for your setup anyhow. :)

Comment: @Mat: It had been a few years since I'd managed my own Eclipse install, and the terrible mess that is Eclipse (too many flavours and versions, and just as many version compatibility issues!) has reminded me why I started switching all my personal (at home) projects over to NetBeans.
I will still probably try to see if the JavaEE flavrour of Eclipse is better, so we can standardize this project's (long-term) development on it, but that will just have to wait until there is time.

Answer (score 11):

You can try and install WTP through the main Ganymede update site:

http://download.eclipse.org/releases/ganymede/

Or you can download the latest [Java EE bundle](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/) and use that instead of your current Eclipse
(do NOT unpack it on top of your current Eclipse, but unpack it elsewhere, to test that second installation: it will come with WTP inside)
Note: check then "[How do I start Eclipse](http://wiki.eclipse.org/IRC_FAQ#How_do_I_start_Eclipse.3F)" to point to your existing workspace in order to see all your previous project in your new Eclipse installation.

---

As mentioned in your link, XSL Tools is now part of WTP (for [Eclipse **3.5 Galileo**](http://www.eclipse.org/galileo/)), and that may explain why your [Eclipse Ganymede (3.4)](http://www.eclipse.org/ganymede/learn.php) might not interpret correctly the P2 update site for WTP (P2 being the new Eclipse provisioning mechanism introduced late in the 3.4 release cycle)

For Eclipse 3.5, you have an XSL Tools installation [illustrated here:](http://www.vogella.de/articles/XSLT/article.html)

[image: link text]

But Eclipse3.4 is more likely to be compatible with [XSLT0.5](http://wiki.eclipse.org/XSL_Release_Plan/ArchivedPlan0.5) and you will need a separate installation, because "XSL Tools" wasn't yet part of WTP.
I am not sure, however, where to find such an installation package within the [Eclipse projects](http://www.eclipse.org/projects/listofprojects.php).

Comment: @VonC: I looked in the Software Update window under Ganymede Site Update. I found "Web and Java EE Development" and truth be told, I had already installed the XML/XSL-related tools. Nothing seemed to change so I posted here. Do I actually have to install *ALL* of the web dev tools just for the XSLT pieces that I want?

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: I have just updated my answer to explain why the update site might not work.

Comment: My god what a mess. :( Is there *any* way I can get some XSLT stuff working in Eclipse 3.4 (if you say no I might cry)? Is there a way that we (the developers with Eclipse 3.4) can do an in-place upgrade to 3.5 to get the XSL parts installed (I *really* don't want to have to go through the support teams to get a new version installed)?

Comment: Thank you, using the update site for Eclipse 3.5 Galileo worked for me. WTP's independent update site is useless.

Comment: The independent site stopped being used around when the simultaneous releases started happening, except for releases that didn't coincide with them.  Older releases might still be there.

Answer (score 10):

Use the following update site :

For Juno :

```
http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/juno/
```

For Indigo :

```
http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/indigo/
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you don't have any firewall exceptions for Eclipse right?

The site for the WTP update is indeed the one you've listed. Maybe post a screenshot? You've added it specifically to your remote update site list?

Either way try a manual update which should be more reliable and get you up and running for now.

All-In-One Update (Eclipse IDE included):

1. Go to the [Eclipse Download](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) site.
2. Grab the all-in-one package: **Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers**
3. Install, have a coffee and enjoy. (WTP is included)

Manual Update your existing installation of Eclipse:

1. Download the applicable [WTP source package](http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/downloads/) to your desktop
2. Shutdown Eclipse
3. Extract the package to your Eclipse installation directory
4. Startup Eclipse. (WTP is now available)

Comment: @Mat Nadrofsky: Manual update is looking like the best bet. Do you know if it (XSLT tools) will work with Eclipse 3.4?

Comment: @Mat: So I tried this: I downloaded the non-SDK version of WTP, and then copies the contents of the downloaded plugins directory to my installation's plugins directory (and did the same with the features directory). It doesn't look like anything's changed, as if Eclipse doesn't even load the plugins. Of course, I'm not sure I installed it right, or that it will work with Eclipse 3.4...

Comment: Can you just start over completely? Download the all-in-one package, rename your existing Eclipse folder, and extract the new Eclipse install? I'm willing to bet you've got some funky stuff going on with your existing folder. Sometimes it's best to start over with a clean slate.

Comment: Interesting, I just notice in the "About Eclipse" window, there is now a WTP button, and if I click on it I get info about all the WTP components installed. Unfortunately, I still don't have access to the XSLT run configuration.

Comment: Here's a sample from the error eclipse log (many other WTP-related messages):
!MESSAGE Unable to satisfy dependency from org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.launching 1.0.100.v201001101919 to requiredCapability: osgi.bundle/org.eclipse.osgi.util/[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director 2 0 2010-02-25 16:54:16.913

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps in the FAQ at http://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_FAQ#How_do_I_install_WTP.3F .

Answer (score 0):

Are you behind a proxy? If so, you need to make sure you configure your proxy settings in Eclipse.

- Window > Preferences

  - General > Network Connections

Comment: There is a corporate proxy, but I've installed other 3rd party plugins, and other Eclipse plugins from the main Eclipse site, so I don't think the local Network folk are blocking this.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the marketplace:

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-java-ee-developer-tools-0

like the site says:

Drag to Install!Drag to your running Eclipse Workspace.